# Casting for two different protocols in Swift

Tags: swift

In **Objective-C** I have the following statement:

```
id<Protocol1, Protocol2> myVar = (id<Protocol1, Protocol2>) [someObject getMyVar];
```

That statement cast the `myVar` into two different protocols. How do I achieve the same result in **Swift**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use optional binding with protocol composition:

```
if let myVar = someObject.getMyVar() as? protocol<Protocol1, Protocol2>   {
    // `myVar` has the type `protocol<Protocol1, Protocol2>`
    // ...
} else {
    // returned value does not conform to Protocol1 and Protocol2.
}
```

Small self-contained example:

```
protocol P1 { }
protocol P2 { }

func test(obj : Any) {
    if let p = obj as? protocol<P1, P2> {
        print("yes")
    } else {
        print("no")
    }
}

struct A { }
struct B : P1 { }
struct C : P2 { }
struct D : P1, P2 { }

test(A()) // no
test(B()) // no
test(C()) // no
test(D()) // yes
```